# React Native Changing State Condtionally

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I have a state item called "isMap" which is a boolean set to false by default, in my header I have a touchable opacity where when pressed will switch isMap to the boolean it currently is not. In my render, I have conditional logic that changes based on the isMap value and this works perfectly. Clicking the header touchable opacity changes the render content on my page.

However, in my header element, I am unable to change the conditional text using the same method I use in the render. I have tried using the _isMounted but this still doesn't work.

```
class NewPostInternal extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Create',
      headerRight: navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.headerRight,
    };
  };

  state = {
    region: {},
    coords: {},
    isMap: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this._isMounted) {
    this.setHeader();
    }
  }

  setHeader() {
      const { isMap } = this.state;
      this.props.navigation.setParams({
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
            isMap: !this.state.isMap
          })}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/icons/region.png')}
            />
///THIS DOESN'T WORK
            {isMap
              ?
              <Text>Shows if true (doesn't change)</Text>
              :
              <Text>Shows if false (doesn't change)</Text>
            }
////
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }


  render() {
    const { isMap } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {
          isMap ?
            <View> <Text> Shows if isMap is true (this works properly)</Text>
               :
            <View> <Text> Shows if isMap is false (this works properly)</Text>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `setHeader()` function only runs once, in `componentDidMount()`.
In this situation the callback passed to onPress only remembers that instant value of `this.state.isMap` from that context.

```js
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
       isMap: !this.state.isMap // ===> this is always the initial value (false)
    })}>
            {isMap
              ?
              <Text>Shows if true (doesn't change)</Text>
              :
              <Text>Shows if false (doesn't change)</Text>
            }
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Try using the state provided by react as a parameter in `this.setState()`, like this:

```js
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState(({ isMap }) => ({ isMap: !isMap }))}>
    {...}
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope it helps!